# Having Trouble accessing objects in an array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I have an array of objects, and I can't figure out how to access other objects inside on the object.

In this case, the array of an object is called `ArrayExam`. I'm trying to access the Objects in the `ExamRoom` class.

I have tried using `ArrayExam[0]->Doc = new Doctor();` but still have no luck.

Any ideas?

Header

```
#include"IOheader.h"

class Person
{
protected:
    string name;
    string MEDcode;
public:
    Person();
    Person(string sName,string sCode);
    void SetName(string sName);
    string ReturnName();
    string ReturnMEDcode();

};


class Doctor : public Person
{
private:
    int room;

public:
    Doctor() :Person() { room = 0; };
    Doctor(string sName, string sCode, int iRoom) : Person(sName, sCode) { room = iRoom; };
    void SetRoom(int iRoom);
    int ReturnRoom();

};

class Patient :public Person
{
private :
    string EMcode;
    int age;
public:
    Patient() :Person() { EMcode = ""; age = 0; };
    Patient(string sName, string sCode,int iAge, string sEMcode) : Person(sName, sCode) { age = iAge; EMcode = sEMcode;};
};

class Child :public Patient
{
public:
    Child() :Patient() {};
    Child(string sName, string sCode, int iAge, string sEMcode) : Patient(sName,sCode,iAge,sEMcode) {};
};

class ExamRoom
{
protected:
    Person *Doc;
    Person *Pat;
    queue <WaitRoom> WaitQue;
public:
    ExamRoom();

};

class WaitRoom
{
private:
    Person *Wait;
public:
    WaitRoom() {};
};

class Hospital
{
private:
    ExamRoom *ArrayExam[50];
public:
    Hospital();
    void Test();
};
```

Functions for headers

```
#include"Header.h"
#include"IOheader.h"

Person::Person()
{
    name = "";
    MEDcode = "";
}

Person::Person(string sName, string sCode)
{
    name = sName;
    MEDcode = sCode;
}

void Person::SetName(string sName)
{
    name = sName;
}

string Person::ReturnName()
{
    return name;
}

string Person::ReturnMEDcode()
{
    return MEDcode;
}

void Doctor::SetRoom(int iRoom)
{
    room = iRoom;
}

int Doctor::ReturnRoom()
{
    return room;

}

ExamRoom::ExamRoom()
{

}

Hospital::Hospital()
{


    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        ArrayExam[i]=new ExamRoom();
    }
}
void Hospital::Test()
{
    ExamRoom A();

}
```

Comment: Your ArrayExam is not an array of objects, it is an array of pointers. If you can use an array (or vector) of objects in your use case, that would be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

The members of `ExamRoom` such as `Doc` are protected. That's why you can't access them. To access them directly such as in `ArrayExam[0]->Doc`, you need to make the members public. Alternatively, you can create "setter" methods to indirectly set the member variables. For example, for `Doc`, you can create a method

```
SetDoc(Person* doc)
{
    this->Doc = doc;
}
```

Since you are manually allocating space for objects such as instances of `ExamRoom`, you should make sure to free all objects that are dynamically created after they are no longer needed.

Comment: Thank you so much!